# How do I set up my compiler to use both the 3.5 SDK and 4.0 SDK in flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compiler-construction, sdk, adobe

There are some classes that were taken out of the 4.0 flex sdk and I would like to know how to configure my compiler to use both sdk's, if it is even possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which classes are missing from the Flex 4.0 SDK that you're looking for?

Comment: mx.automation.delegates.controls.AlertAutomationImpl;
mx.automation.delegates.controls.AlertFormAutomationImpl;

Answer (score 0):

Just include a reference to the libraries of the other SDK you are using and pass them to the compiler. You could also just put only the files you need in the sourcepath of your application, which might be a lot easier.

I'm not sure if things will be compatible though and I guess you'll be in quite some trouble.